# Can Snap.svg be used just server side with Node.js? (Not through the browser)

Tags: node.js, svg, snap.svg

I need to create and manipulate some SVGs just with some server-side code (like with cron jobs) but I'm wondering if it's possible to use Snap.svg in this scenario where it's not included in a web page.

Will this work without Snap.svg being run in a browser?

Comment: Not sure about Node, but you can with PhantomJS or similar.

Comment: @Ian Thanks, that's actually what I'm looking into right now.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) to simulate browser environments and natively run Snap.svg in Node.js.

Example:

```js
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const xmlserializer = require('xmlserializer');

jsdom.env('', [require.resolve('snapsvg')], (error, window) => {
    if (error) throw error;

    const paper = window.Snap(100, 100);

    const rect = paper.rect(20, 20, 60, 60);
    rect.attr({fill: 'red'});

    const svg = xmlserializer.serializeToString(paper.node);
    window.close();

    console.log(svg);
});
```

Prints:

```xml
<svg height="100" version="1.1" width="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><desc>Created with Snap</desc><defs/><rect x="20" y="20" width="60" height="60" style="" fill="#ff0000"/></svg>
```

Comment: jsdom does not implement getBBox... so it is a pretty unuseful

Comment: I'm interested in headless/cloud SnapSVG, maybe this JSDOM+Node-Canvas (SVG capable) implementation might be help, [Paper-jsdom-canvas](https://github.com/paperjs/paper-jsdom-canvas)